# Air pollution and measurements: deciliter vs cubic meters

Tags: unit-of-measure

If a deciliter of air has 5000 micrograms, how much would be in a cubic meter? (Particulate matter smaller than 2.5 microns is measured in decileters, larger than 2.5 are generally measured in cubic meters).
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** there are 1000 liters in a cubic meter and deci stands for 1/10

Comment: So, 1000 x 5000 x 10 = 50 million micrograms per cubic meters?

Comment: Micro is 1/1000000. You can further simplify the answer